# Issue with SQL query not running via JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g, pivot, jdbctemplate

I am having this strange issue where a sql query which is using Oracle Pivot syntax. I can run the query in SqlDeveloper with no issues; however, running it through JdbcTemplate with a RowMapper give this strange error about invalid column name.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar ... nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
```

SQL statement:

```
select * from ( 
    Select stat.SWRHXML_HXPS_CODE  
    FROM Swbhxml xml 
    LEFT JOIN Swrhxml stat ON stat.swrhxml_trans_id = xml.SWBHXML_TRANS_ID 
    WHERE stat.SWRHXML_ACTIVITY_DATE = (
        SELECT MAX(st.SWRHXML_ACTIVITY_DATE) 
        FROM swrhxml st 
        WHERE stat.SWRHXML_TRANS_ID = st.SWRHXML_TRANS_ID)
   ) pivot (count(SWRHXML_HXPS_CODE) 
       for SWRHXML_HXPS_CODE in 
        ('NEW','EXPORT_READY','PENDING_MATCH','MATCHED_ID','PROCESSED','REJECTED'));
```

Row Mapper:

```
public class TranscriptStatusCountRowMapper implements RowMapper {

    @Override
    public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        TranscriptStatusCounts tsc = new TranscriptStatusCounts();

        tsc.setNewCount(rs.getLong("NEW_RECORDS"));
        tsc.setExportReadyCount(rs.getLong("EXPORT_READY"));
        tsc.setPendingMatchCount(rs.getLong("PENDING_MATCH"));
        tsc.setMatchedIdCount(rs.getLong("MATCHED_ID"));
        tsc.setProcessedCount(rs.getLong("PROCESSED"));
        tsc.setRejectedCount(rs.getLong("REJECTED"));
        return tsc;
    }
}
```

DAO calling class:

```
@Repository("transcriptCountDao")
public class TranscriptCountDaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl implements   TranscriptCountDao {

    private static final Logger logger =    Logger.getLogger(TranscriptCountDaoImpl.class);

    @Override
    public TranscriptStatusCounts findTranscriptStatusCount() {
        logger.debug("Getting counts of Transcripts status in system"); 
        String sql =  "...sql posted above..."
        TranscriptStatusCounts tsc = 
            (TranscriptStatusCounts) getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new TranscriptStatusCountRowMapper());   
        return tsc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... well I figured it out...

The Pivot table columns don't really map to well to my row mapper.  So, I change the row mapper to the following which solved the issue:

```
TranscriptStatusCounts tsc = new TranscriptStatusCounts();
    //'NEW','EXPORT_READY','PENDING_MATCH','MATCHED_ID','PROCESSED','REJECTED'
    tsc.setNewCount(rs.getLong(1));
    tsc.setExportReadyCount(rs.getLong(2));
    tsc.setPendingMatchCount(rs.getLong(3));
    tsc.setMatchedIdCount(rs.getLong(4));
    tsc.setProcessedCount(rs.getLong(5));
    tsc.setRejectedCount(rs.getLong(6));
    return tsc;
```

I forgot that the sql "Invalid Column Name" error can also refer to the name used in the resultSet to access the column.  Because the PIVOT query orders them, I can use just the number of the column to get back the results.

Comment: this also explains why, when tried this with jpa as native query I had such issues.